# Update the data on same page when user select item from search list

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am New in angular js and I need update the data when the user select the any option from the search box then update the data as per the selection of user on same page for example when user select java then java related data in col-lg-8 class also should I use one or two json file.My code is
    
    
    
    AutoComplete

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js">
</script>
<script>
 var app=angular.module('demo',['ui.bootstrap']);
 app.controller('autoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('auto.json').success(function(data) {
 $scope.myCourse = data;
 $scope.detail=details;
 });
 });
</script>
<style>
.container{
    margin-top: 7%;
}
.gry{
background-color: rgb(220,220,220);

    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="autoCtrl">
<div class="col-lg-3 gry" >
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h3>Search Courses..</h3>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g:Java,Php" ng-model="selectedCourse" typeahead="name as     name.course for name in myCourse | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:4">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
<h3>Search Result...</h3>
<div></div>
<div>{{ data should be refelected here...}}</div>
<div>{{ data should be refelected here...}}</div>
<div>{{ data should be refelected here...}}</div>
</div>
</div>        
</body>
</html>
```